# Is there a way to prevent a child directory from referencing the node_modules directory in its parent directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Assuming the following directory structure:

```
main-app
├── node_modules
├── package.json
└── test-app
   ├── node_modules
   └── package.json
```

test-app has a separate package.json file to ensure that it does not depend on its parent directory. However, when moving and executing test-app in a different directory (e.g. /tmp/test-app), it fails to start. Upon further investigation, it was discovered that test-app was referencing the node_modules directory in main-app, where it found the missing packages that allowed it to run successfully.

This makes it difficult to determine whether test-app is running independently or just happens to work because of the parent directory's node_modules. Is it possible to prevent child directories from referencing their parent directory's node_modules directory?

#### Expected behavior

Expected behavior when stopping ancestor references by some means:

1. test-app expects not to reference ../node_modules.
2. It is expected that an error occurs when the required packages for test-app are not listed in test-app/package.json.

#### System configuration

node: 16.19.1

Comment: If you want it to run independently, don't put projects inside other projects, make them siblings. Because right now `node` is literally doing what it was designed to do: check the current dir, if it can't find the module, move up a dir and look for it there. And keep doing that until you run out of dirs. What you describe as "expected behaviour" is not expected at all, what made you think that's what was supposed to happen? (See [this chart](https://nodejs.org/docs/v16.0.0/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) for the authoritative details)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you for your advice!
To be honest, I am trying to create an example of how to use the package I created in main-app by creating a subdirectory called test-app for users.
This is similar to having a doc directory at the root of the project.
Therefore, even if there is a test-app in main-app, it should not be an unnatural configuration.

It is convenient that it can search by following ancestors.
However, I feel that it is inconvenient that there is no mechanism to stop ancestor references.

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/8830

Comment: It is okay to have a test-app within the project. But the node_modules referencing issue actually doesn't matter. You should never copy or version control a node_modules folder. You have the package.json and package-lock.json, then just run `npm i` once. You should always run `npm i` anyway to ensure dependencies integrity after moving a project. Remember the node_modules folder does not define your project, package.json does.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for teaching me. It was very interesting content. In my case, the problem was not realizing that I was being referenced, but it was pointed out that there were also security issues.

Comment: @RickyMo If the test-app is running independently, even if it is located under main-app, the dependency can be maintained without depending on the parent package by not managing it further. Currently, I am copying main-app/test-app to /tmp/test-app and working on it to ensure that it runs independently, and then returning /tmp/test-app to main-app/test-app. It is very troublesome.